# Borrar elemento con menor frecuencia con Arrays

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que consiste en borrar los elementos o el elemento que tenga la menor frecuencia en una serie, por ejemplo 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4 este seria mi Array, y la salida seria 
1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3 porque 2 y 4 son el elemento con la repetición mas baja y ambos coinciden en numero de repeticiones.

Para ello he realizado un bucle recorre dicho array y he creado varios métodos que me dicen tanto quien es el numero mas pequeño y que frecuencia tiene dentro del array, en ese bucle tengo un if con una condición que me dice si la frecuencia del numero es la misma que la frecuencia que la del menor. Y mi problema viene aquí... consigue eliminar los numeros que coinciden con la condición excepto uno, ese sale con el restante que no cumple la condición, llevo un rato mirando y no consigo solucionarlo, si alguien puede mirarlo y decirme como mejorarlo o que punto de vista me falta lo agradecería

```
public class Ejercicio5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int n = 0;
        int tam = 30;
        int numero [] = new int [tam];

        n = llenar(numero,n);

        System.out.println(toString(numero,n));

        int menor = menosRepetido(numero,n); // Nos devuelve el numero que menos se repite

        System.out.println("El numero que se repite menos veces : " + menor);

        int rep = numeroRepetido(menor,numero,n);

        System.out.println("Numero 1 se repite : " + rep);

        System.out.println("Numero 2 se repite : " + numeroRepetido(2,numero,n));

        System.out.println("Numero 5 se repite : " + numeroRepetido(5,numero,n));

        //n = eliminar(numero,n,1);

        //System.out.println(toString(numero,n));

        n = elimarMenosRepetido(numero,n,menor);

        System.out.println(toString(numero,n));


    }

    public static int llenar (int numero [], int n) {

        int s [] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5};

        for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {

            numero[i] = s[i];
            n++;

        }

        return n;
    }

    public static int numeroRepetido(int num, int numero [], int n) {

        int contador = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            if(numero[i]==num) {

                contador++;

            }

        }

        return contador;

    }

    public static int menosRepetido(int numero [], int n) {

        int menor = numero[1];

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            if(numeroRepetido(numero[i],numero,n)<numeroRepetido(menor,numero,n)) {

                menor = numero[i];

            }

        }

        return menor;


    }

    public static int eliminar(int numero [],int n , int num) {

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {

                if(numero[i]==num) {

                        for(int k=i; k<n; k++) {

                            numero[k] = numero[k+1];

                        }

                        n--;
                    }

                }

        }


        return n;

    }

    public static int elimarMenosRepetido(int numero [],int n,int menor) {

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {

                if(numeroRepetido(numero[i],numero,n)==numeroRepetido(menor,numero,n)) {

                    for(int k=i; k<n; k++) {

                        numero[k] = numero[k+1];

                    }

                    n--;

                }

            }

        }

        return n;

    }

    public static String toString(int numero [], int n) {

        String s = "";

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            s = s + numero[i] + " ";

        }

        return s;

    }

}
```

**Mi salida : 2 5 5 5 5 5**

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo una forma mejor de solucionar este ejercicio.

Si utilizas `HashMap` te permitirá guardar una `Clave` asociada a un `Valor`. Es bastante sencillo de usar y te permitirá tener el código mucho más claro y con menos líneas de código.

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] lista = {3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,8,8};
    Map<Integer, Integer> repetidos = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int numero: lista){
      Integer vecesRepetido = repetidos.get(numero);

      if (vecesRepetido == null){
        vecesRepetido = 0;
      }
      repetidos.put(numero, vecesRepetido+1);
    }
    System.out.println(repetidos.toString()); // {3=2, 4=2, 5=4, 6=1, 8=2}

    // Borramos el menos repetido
      Integer keyMenosRepetido = null;
      Integer valueMenosRepetido = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : repetidos.entrySet()) {

      if(keyMenosRepetido == null){
        keyMenosRepetido = entry.getKey();
        valueMenosRepetido = entry.getValue();
      }

      if(valueMenosRepetido > entry.getValue()){
        keyMenosRepetido = entry.getKey();
        valueMenosRepetido = entry.getValue();
      }
    }
    repetidos.remove(keyMenosRepetido);
    System.out.println(repetidos.toString()); // {3=2, 4=2, 5=4, 8=2}
  }
}
```

Tras declarar la `lista` y el `HashMap`, recorres la lista.

Mientras recorres `lista`, le preguntas que valor (cuantas veces se repite) tiene en el `HashMap`.

- Si no existe ese numero devolverá null, por lo que pones la variable a 0 para que sume 1  al valor de la clave.
- Si existe, tendrá un número asignado, por lo que sumará 1.

## HashMap `put()`

```java
nombreMap.put(K clave, V valor);
```

Añade un elemento al HashMap (sobreescribiendo si existe). Por eso debes actualizarlo sumando uno a `V` (su valor).

## HashMap `get()`

```java
nombreMap.get(K clave);
```

Te permite obtener `V` el valor de una clave. En este caso si hicieramos `repetidos.get(8)` devolvería 2.

## HashMap `getKey()` y `getValue()`

En un bucle donde recorremos un mapa `entrySet()`, nos permitirá obtener la clave y valor de cada elemento en cada iteración del bucle.

Con esto tan solo deberemos comparar para ver cual es el mas pequeño hasta que termine el bucle.